# Плавное обновление новых внесенных данных в бд

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

есть index.php

```html
<div id='content'></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```js
var container = document.getElementById("content");
function getSum()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "demo.php");
    req.send();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        {
            container.innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function()
{
    getSum();
}, 2000);
```

ну и в demo.php я вывожу что-то там из бд. Всё работает чудесно, данные обновляются в "живом времени", но вот хотелось бы сделать это немного красивее, чтобы новые данные появлялись плавно а не мгновенно. В js не силен, помогите пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что по вашему значит плавно? появлялись по  символу в минуту?

Comment: нет, не по символу. Анимация что ли какая-то, я даже не знаю как правильно описать это. Что-то типа opactiy, эффект затухания какого-то, что-то в этом роде

Comment: https://jquery-docs.ru/toggle/ Добавляете Div например изначально скрытый, и применяете к нему сию функцию, предварительно поместив в него данные

Comment: можете предоставить пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Загляните по ссылке, там есть пример, и не один.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если планируете использовать jquery, попробуйте вот так изменить функцию:

```js
function getSum() {
    $.get( "demo.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#content" ).hide().html( data.responseText ).fadeIn( 3000 );
    });
}
```

Не забудьте добавить подключение библиотеки jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

fadein принимает параметр в миллисекундах. И плавно проявляет блок.